# How can I print the currency $ in the salary fields? I am using two-way binding

Tags: angular

```
<td>
  <input
    type="number"
    [(ngModel)]="data.salary | currency: 'USD'"
    (ngModelChange)="data.salary = $event"
   
  />
</td>
```

Angular salary pipes. I was trying print $ in the salary fields of the table but it says that  `Parser Error: Unexpected token, expected identifier' or 'keyword at the end of the expression [data.salary | currency: 'USD'=$event]`. Can anyone help me out it thank you.

Comment: you can't do that, because the value in ngModel must be get and set. Why not add currency in the component and not in the template?

Comment: Do you need to use 2 way binding here? If you pull the value from the component, you can simply use it in the template. `{{data.salary | currency}}`. For USD, you do not need to pass in the currency symbol. I would recommend avoiding two-way binding and instead using a 1 way binding pattern.